# SQL check if a record has a reference from another table and if so do something

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, `users` and `friendships`

```
id   |  name   | password              
-------------------------
 1    |  Dave   | 1234   
-------------------------
 2    |  John   | abcd   
-------------------------
 3    |  Bob    | xyz    
-------------------------
```

and the `friendships`

```
 friend_one   |  friend_two   | status              
 -------------------------------------
       1      |      1        |   me
 -------------------------------------
       2      |      2        |   me   
 -------------------------------------
       3      |      3        |   me    
 ------------------------------------
       1      |      2        | pending
 -------------------------------------
       3      |      1        | active
```

Now whenever a user logged in to the system, I need to fetch all the users in the database, also I need to add an extra column to the result from the select query, which shows the friendship status with currently logged in user.

For example, user id 1 , Dave logged in to the system and request for users list, select query should be output as below,

```
id   |  name   | password  | friend_status            
------------------------------------------
 1    |  Dave   | 1234     |   me
------------------------------------------ 
 2    |  John   | abcd     |   pending
------------------------------------------
 3    |  Bob    | xyz      |   active
------------------------------------------
```

When the user id 2, John logged in to the system, he need to get the below table,

```
 id   |  name   | password  | friend_status            
------------------------------------------
 1    |  Dave   | 1234     |   pending
------------------------------------------ 
 2    |  John   | abcd     |   me
------------------------------------------
 3    |  Bob    | xyz      |   null
------------------------------------------
```

Is this even possible ? I tried to join tables and use a nested query

For example, with the below query I can get all the friendships for the currently logged in user,

```
select * from friendships
where friend_one = 2 or friend_two = 2
```

But I don't understand what to do next. I tried to put this as a nested query of the main select query and tried to join tables but I'm not getting what I wanted.

Can anyone give me an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `CROSS JOIN` the list of `id` values from `users` with the `users` table to get all distinct pairs of `id` values, then `LEFT JOIN` that to the `friendships` table to get the friend `status` for each user:

```
SELECT u1.id, u.name, u.password,
       f.status
FROM users u
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id
            FROM users) u1
LEFT JOIN friendships f ON f.friend_one = u.id  AND f.friend_two = u1.id
                        OR f.friend_one = u1.id AND f.friend_two = u.id
ORDER BY u1.id, u.id
```

Output:

```
id  name    password    status
1   Dave    1234        me
1   John    abcd        pending
1   Bob     xyz         active
2   Dave    1234        pending
2   John    abcd        me
2   Bob     xyz         (null)
3   Dave    1234        active
3   John    abcd        (null)
3   Bob     xyz         me
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e0aa1/9)

To get a specific user, just add `WHERE u1.id = ?` before the `ORDER BY` clause.